# I need to create sql query with linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model

```
public class GrandPrix
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public int? ChampionchipId { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Championchip Championchip { get; set; }
}
    public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

//    public virtual ICollection<GrandPrix> GrandPrix { get; set; } 
}
```

I need modify in

```
ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "Name");
```

db.Locations
.Where(l=>l.id is not contained in db.Grandprix.Where(g=>g.ChampionchipId == 1))

this query it work

```
SELECT Locations.Id as Id, Locations.Name as Name FROM dbo.Locations WHERE Locations.Id Not In (SELECT GrandPrixes.LocationId FROM GrandPrixes WHERE ChampionchipId = 1)
```

sorry my English and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Locations.Where(loc=>loc.GrandPrixes.Any(gp=>gp.ChampionshipId != 1))
```

should give you locations if your FK relationships are set up properly.

Else

```
var gps = db.GrandPrixes.Where(gp=>gp.ChampionshipId == 1)
                        .Select(gp=>gp.Location.LocationId).ToList();
db.Locations.Where(loc=>!gps.Any(gp=>gp == loc.LocationId))
```

Comment: `public ActionResult Create(int championchipId = 0) { var gpx = db.GrandPrix .Where(gp => gp.ChampionchipId == championchipId) .Select(gp => gp.Location.Id).ToList(); ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.Locations.Where(loc=>gpx.All(gp => gp != loc.Id)), "Id", "Name"); ViewBag.ChampionchipId = new SelectList(db.Championchips, "Id", "Year", championchipId); return View(); }` Work fine. Thank you.